# Box enterprise events missing event for share link permission change

Tags: box-api

We are interested in getting the enterprise events from Box API which are documented [here](http://developers.box.com/docs/#events). I see that there are enterprise events for items being shared and unshared. These are `SHARE` and `UNSHARE`. However there are no events when permission(access level) are changed for shared links. So e.g if someone changes the access level from `OPEN` to `YOUR_COMPANY` or vice-versa, the Box API does not send any event..Our use-case is such that we would like to known when the access level changed. How can this be achieved?

Do we need to submit a feature request to Box? If so, what is the process? Also, what can be the timelines for any new revisions in which this feature can be added?

Answer (score 0):

Good catch.  Consider you feature request submitted.

Comment: Is it possible to get an idea of the ETA? I know it sounds a bit impatient, but I would like to have a rough estimate.